# Logistic Regression Odds Interpret

Tags: r, logistic, odds

I was  analyzing the different treatments applied to products. It started out with a a plethora of variables but I came to the conclusion
that I can essentially only control the treatment applied so I only wanted to calculate those odds and dropped all other variables that I cannot control.

```
Status = c('Fail','Pass','Pass','Fail','Fail','Fail','Fail','Fail','Fail','Fail','Fail','Fail','Pass','Fail','Pass','Pass','Fail','Fail','Fail','Fail','Fail','Fail','Pass','Fail','Pass','Fail','Fail','Fail','Fail','Fail','Pass','Fail','Pass','Pass','Pass','Pass','Pass','Pass','Pass','Pass')
Treatment = c('B','C','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','Z','B','B','B','B','B','C','C','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','C','Z','Z','Z','Z','Z','Z','Z','Z','Z','Z')

length(X)
length(D)
df = cbind(Status,Treatment)
df = as.data.frame(df)
xtabs(~Status + Treatment,data = df)
mylogit <- glm(Status ~ Treatment, data = df,family = "binomial")
exp(cbind(OR = coef(mylogit), confint(mylogit)))
```

I want to make sure that I am interpreting the results correctly.

Treatment Z increases the odds of Pass by 1200%

Treatment C increases the odds of Pass by a factor 0f 44%

Also, where do I get the odds for Treatment B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provided estimates the logit with an intercept, so that's why Treatment B is not appearing. Otherwise, you would have a perfect multicollinearity problem and the coefficients would not be interpretable. The coefficient on Z is the unit increase in log odds over Treatment B, the coefficient on C is the unit increase in log odds over Treatment B, and the intercept coefficient is the log odds of Treatment B. For reference, this is the output from the R code in the question:

```
                    OR      2.5 %     97.5 %
(Intercept)  0.3750000 0.13454740  0.9119271
TreatmentC   0.4444444 0.02120948  3.4397196
TreatmentZ  12.0000000 2.30808827 95.7410385
```

So:

1. The odds of pass for Treatment B is $0.375$.
2. The odds of pass for Treatment C are 0.444 times the odds for Treatment B, so $0.375 \times 0.444 = 0.167$.
3. The odds of pass for Treatment Z are 12.00 times the odds for Treatment B, so $0.375 \times 12.00 = 4.50$.

If you exclude the intercept from the logit estimation (which you do by appending `-1` to the formula in R, if you didn't know already), you will actually see the results I calculated above directly.

```
> mylogit_no_intercept <- glm(Status ~ Treatment-1, data = df,family = "binomial")
> exp(coef(mylogit_no_intercept))
TreatmentB TreatmentC TreatmentZ 
 0.3750000  0.1666667  4.5000000
```

Comment: No, odds are not probabilities so you don't use the % sign when discussing odds and you never multiply odds by 100.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Thanks for pointing that out. I didn't notice that the percent could be misinterpreted as probabilities. I've edited my answer to convert the percents back to decimals.

Comment: @FrankHarrell when reporting this I can say treatment Z odds for success are 12 times greater than treatment B and treatment C will yield roughly half the odds for success as treatment B.

Comment: Yes, and include confidence intervals in those statements.